# How to speed up the computation of a specific array

Tags: matrix, performance-tuning

I am doing some calculations on superconductivity and I REALLY need to speed up the way I calculate one of my arrays. I will put the input to the matrix (of course a tiny toy model of what I am doing), just in case somebody wants to time it, but the important part, and the part which I am asking for help about is `delta`, which is in the lower part.

Input to the matrix:

```
nn = 2; Nband = 2;
Nstates = 2*nn*Nband;

eigenvectors = Table[Range[Nstates] + i, {i, 1, Nstates}];

InverseFlatten[l_, dimensions_] := Fold[Partition, Flatten@l, Most[Reverse[dimensions]]];
uv = InverseFlatten[eigenvectors, {Nstates, Nband, 2, nn}];
u = uv[[1 ;; Nstates, 1 ;; Nband, 1]];
v = uv[[1 ;; Nstates, 1 ;; Nband, 2]];
f = Range[Nstates];
V = Table[Which[i == j + 1, 2], 
    {l, 1, Nband}, {m, 1, Nband}, {s, 1, Nband},{q, 1, Nband}, {i, 1, nn}, {j, 1, nn}];
```

Now, first I naively started by doing in it in a intuitive way, but it turned to be crazily slow!!

```
delta = Table[
         Table[Which[i == j + 1, 
           Sum[V[[μ, ν, q, s, i, j]]*Sum[u[[n, q, i]]*v[[n, s, j]]*f[[n]],
           {n, 1, Nstates}],{q, 1, Nband}, {s, 1, Nband}]],
         {i, 1, nn}, {j, 1, nn}],
        {μ, 1, Nband}, {ν, 1, Nband}];
```

Then thanks to this forum, I learned that one should avoid `Sum` and that it was smarter to do `Dot` products of arrays and to use `Total`, then I wrote:

```
delta = 
 Table[
   Total[Flatten[V[[μ, ν, ;; , ;; , ;; , ;;]]*
      Table[
         Table[
            Which[
                i == j + 1,
                f.(u[[;; , q, i]]*Conjugate[v[[;; , s, j]]])    ], 
              {i, 1, nn}, {j, 1, nn}],
          {q, 1, Nband}, {s, 1, Nband}], 1]], 
     {μ, 1, Nband}, {ν, 1, Nband}];
```

But this is still toooo slow.

Does any of the bright minds of this forum see a faster way to compute `delta`?
If somebody wants to time it using `Timing`, can make it bigger by increasing `nn` and `Nband`, in my real calculations `nn` goes up to 600 and `Nband` up to 5.

(I do not care about the `Null` elements, just need the non `Null` elements)

Thanks

Comment: Dear Mencia, after 25 question you sure can do better with regard to formatting your post?

Comment: @Yves Klett I tried to figure that out by putting in this forum, "how to format a quiestion", but did not find anything. Where can I find that? I definitely want to format, forsurwe

Comment: Please have a look at: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/formatting. And/Or have a look at the edits to your questions (or any other Q) which will show you how the markdown works.

Comment: Most importantly, for code you simply indent by four spaces (look at my minimal edit).

Comment: Yay! Much better :D

Comment: @Yves Klett thanks!!!

Comment: Now, for that pro feeling you could even replace the fancy typesetting garble like `\[Mu]` using @halirutan´s answer here: http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1043/131

Comment: At a quick glance, I think the delta calculation could be compiled (http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Compile.html). The naive version is actually a better starting point. With `CompilationTarget->"C"` you should obtain good performance.

Comment: @Ajasja thanks so much, I see if I can conbine "Compile" with the naive way to calculate delta.

Comment: @Mencia are you sure that both of your versions give the correct result? The results do not look identical.

Comment: @Anon thanks for the remark. Precisely they are not identical in the Null elements, but as I said I will only use the non Null elements, therefore, those are the ones that should be identical, both the number and the position in the final array.

Comment: @Mencia It's always good to work with `PackedArrays` http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3496/what-is-a-mathematica-packed-array, which means that `Null`s can't be part of the array.

Comment: @Ajasja do Null elements occupy memory?

Comment: @Mencia Of course they do. Do read about PackedArray. The bottom line is that you have to have an array (a list) where all elements are of the same type.

Comment: As an example ``(*Array of one type*)
na = ConstantArray[Null, 100];
Print@ByteCount@na;
Print@Developer`PackedArrayQ@na;

(*Array of floats*)
na = ConstantArray[1., 100];
Print@ByteCount@na;
Print@Developer`PackedArrayQ@na;

(*make mixed array*)
na[[1]] = Null;
Print@ByteCount@na;
Print@Developer`PackedArrayQ@na;``

Comment: `TensorContract` works fine for packed arrays.

Comment: @Ajasja how do I create a packed array, I tried for example: V = Table[
   Which[i == j + 1, 2, True, 0], {l, 1, Nband}, {m, 1, Nband}, {s, 1,
     Nband}, {q, 1, Nband}, {i, 1, nn}, {j, 1, nn}];Developer`ToPackedArray@V; but stil not packed.

Comment: @Mencia You have to do `V = Developer`ToPackedArray@V`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ParallelTable` command...

```
nn = 100; Nband = 5;
Nstates = 2*nn*Nband;

eigenvectors = ParallelTable[Range[Nstates] + i, {i, 1, Nstates}];

InverseFlatten[l_, dimensions_] := 
 Fold[Partition, Flatten@l, Most[Reverse[dimensions]]];
uv = InverseFlatten[eigenvectors, {Nstates, Nband, 2, nn}];
u = uv[[1 ;; Nstates, 1 ;; Nband, 1]];
v = uv[[1 ;; Nstates, 1 ;; Nband, 2]];
f = Range[Nstates];
V = ParallelTable[
Which[i == j + 1, 2], {l, 1, Nband}, {m, 1, Nband}, {s, 1, 
Nband}, {q, 1, Nband}, {i, 1, nn}, {j, 1, nn}];

delta1 = ParallelTable[
 Total[Flatten[
   V[[μ, ν, ;; , ;; , ;; , ;;]]*
    Table[Table[
      Which[i == j + 1, 
       f.(u[[;; , q, i]]*Conjugate[v[[;; , s, j]]])], {i, 1, 
       nn}, {j, 1, nn}], {q, 1, Nband}, {s, 1, Nband}], 
   1]], {μ, 1, Nband}, {ν, 1, Nband}] /. {Null -> 
  0}; // Timing
```

For me it gives result {11.407000, Null}

Without parallel command...

```
delta = Table[
 Total[Flatten[
   V[[μ, ν, ;; , ;; , ;; , ;;]]*
    Table[Table[
      Which[i == j + 1, 
       f.(u[[;; , q, i]]*Conjugate[v[[;; , s, j]]])], {i, 1, 
       nn}, {j, 1, nn}], {q, 1, Nband}, {s, 1, Nband}], 
   1]], {μ, 1, Nband}, {ν, 1, Nband}] /. {Null -> 
  0}; // Timing
```

{23.768000, Null}